# Incorrect behaviour of Locator inside Show?

Tags: plotting, dynamic

Why doesn't `Locator` behave correctly in the following code?

```
BezierPoint[t_, cps_] := Block[{tt},
   tt = {(1 - t)^3, 3 t (1 - t)^2, 3 t^2 (1 - t), t^3};
   Sum[cps[[i]]*tt[[i]], {i, 1, 4}]
   ];

DiskBezierRadius[t_, ri_] := Block[{tt},
   tt = {(1 - t)^3, 3 t (1 - t)^2, 3 t^2 (1 - t), t^3};
   Sum[ri[[i]] tt[[i]], {i, 1, 4}]
   ];

ControlPoints = {{100, 100}, {100, 300}, {300, 200}, {300, 
    100}};
ControlRadii = {50, 50, 20, 20};
Dynamic[Show[
  ParametricPlot[BezierPoint[t, ControlPoints], {t, 0, 1}],
  Graphics[
   Table[p = BezierPoint[t, ControlPoints]; {Text[t, p], 
     Circle[p, 5]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]],
  Graphics[
   {
    Line[ControlPoints[[1 ;; 2]]],
    Line[ControlPoints[[3 ;; 4]]],
    Blue,
    Locator[Dynamic[ControlPoints[[1]]]],
    Locator[Dynamic[ControlPoints[[2]]]],
    Locator[ControlPoints[[3]]],
    Locator[ControlPoints[[4]]]
    }
   ],
  Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400}}
  ]]
Dynamic[ControlPoints[[1]]]
```

[image]

If I wrap into `Dynamic` two locators (as in code above) then I have both locators dragged by mouse. I mean if I drag one locator, then both locator move. I can't drag only one locator.

If I wrap only one (second) locator, then it can be dragged alone.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use a `Manipulate`, it would avoid some of the `Dynamic` complexity:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[BezierPoint[t, pts], {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400}}],
  Graphics[
   {
    Red, Thick,
    BezierCurve[pts],
    Gray,
    Line[{pts[[1]], pts[[2]]}],
    Line[{pts[[-1]], pts[[-2]]}],
    Table[
     {
      Gray, Disk[BezierPoint[t, pts], 10],
      White, Text[t, BezierPoint[t, pts]]
      }, {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]
    }],
  Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic
  ],
 {pts, Locator},
 Initialization :> {pts = ControlPoints}]
```

[image: animation]

There's a problem with the locators obscuring the text at the start and end. I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: I believe setting the locator appearance to none will suppress it but still allow interactivity that will allow the desired functionality with the desired presentation,e.g. I used it in my answer

Answer (score 3):

I apologise for not directly answering your question but provide an alternative. `LocatorPane` is useful when dealing with multiple locators. Does produce the desired behaviour (assuming your functions are iniitialized and I have omitted display of control point 1):

```
DynamicModule[{
  ControlPoints = {{100, 100}, {100, 300}, {300, 200}, {300, 100}},
  ControlRadii = {{50, 50, 20, 20}}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[ControlPoints],
  Dynamic@
   Show[ParametricPlot[BezierPoint[t, ControlPoints], {t, 0, 1}], 
    Graphics[
     Table[p = BezierPoint[t, ControlPoints]; {Text[t, p], 
       Circle[p, 10]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]], 
    Graphics[{Line[ControlPoints[[1 ;; 2]]], 
      Line[ControlPoints[[3 ;; 4]]], Point[Dynamic@ControlPoints]}], 
    Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400}}], Appearance->None
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Introduction

It appears to me that this might be a bug.  I certainly cannot think of any other explanation, but I would be glad if there is one.

The issue is with `ParametricPlot`, but I cannot explain *why* there should be a problem.  Each `Locator` is basically an `EventHandler` that, when activated, tracks changes in position of the mouse and updates the coordinates of the `Locator` accordingly.  What seems to happen is that a mousedown in one `Locator` activates all `Locators` when the graphics includes a `ParametricPlot` that depends on the `Locator` points.  This somehow causes all dynamic locators to be updated whenever one dynamic locator is dragged.

It does not appear to be a localization issue or a kernel vs. front end variable issue -- that is, putting variables in `Module` or `DynamicModule` did not help.

As shown in other answers, the issue does not occur with `LocatorPane`, which creates a single event handler for the locators.

---

There is another issue in the OP's code.  Since `p` is not localized and is set (several times) inside a `Dynamic`, there is continual updating.

---

### One fix

Here is a fix of the OP's code that preserves the behavior of `Locators`, in case that is preferred over the behavior of `LocatorPane`.

```
Dynamic[With[{param = BezierPoint[t, ControlPoints]},
  Show[
   (* replace ParametricPlot *)
   Graphics[Line[Table[param, {t, 0, 1, 1/100}]]],
   (* localize p *)
   Graphics[Table[With[{p = param}, {Text[t, p], Circle[p, 5]}], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]],
   Graphics[{
     Line[ControlPoints[[1 ;; 2]]], Line[ControlPoints[[3 ;; 4]]],
     Blue,
     Locator[Dynamic[ControlPoints[[1]]]],
     Locator[Dynamic[ControlPoints[[2]]]],
     Locator[(*Dynamic@*)ControlPoints[[3]]],
     Locator[(*Dynamic@*)ControlPoints[[4]]]}],
   Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400}}]
  ]]
```

### Another example and some evidence

Here is further evidence that the issue lies with `ParametricPlot`.  [This example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Locator.html#1443139356) from the `Locator` reference page works fine:

```
DynamicModule[{v1 = {2, 0}, v2 = {-1, 1}}, 
 Dynamic @ Graphics[{Circle[], Red, 
    GeometricTransformation[Circle[], Transpose[{v1, v2}]], Green, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, v1}], Line[{{0, 0}, v2}], Locator[Dynamic[v1]], 
    Locator[Dynamic[v2]]}, PlotRange -> 3]]
```

But if we replace the circles with a `ParametricPlot`, we get an example similar to the OP's, and the locators are linked as in the OP's.

```
DynamicModule[{v1 = {2, 0}, v2 = {-1, 1}},
 Dynamic @ Show[
   ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, v1 Cos[t] + v2 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
   Graphics[{(*Circle[],Red,GeometricTransformation[Circle[],
     Transpose[{v1,v2}]],*)
     Green, Line[{{0, 0}, v1}], Line[{{0, 0}, v2}],
     Locator[Dynamic[v1]], Locator[Dynamic[v2]]}],
   Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 3
   ]]
```

The locators are still linked if we move the symbols outside `ParametricPlot` and insert an evaluated parametrization:

```
DynamicModule[{v1 = {2, 0}, v2 = {-1, 1}},
 Dynamic @ With[{param = v1 Cos[t] + v2 Sin[t]},
   Show[
    ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, param}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
    Graphics[{
      Green, Line[{{0, 0}, v1}], Line[{{0, 0}, v2}],
      Locator[Dynamic[v1]], Locator[Dynamic[v2]]}],
    Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 3
    ]]]
```

Even if extract the `Lines` from the `ParametricPlot`, the locators are still linked.

```
DynamicModule[{v1 = {2, 0}, v2 = {-1, 1}},
 Dynamic @ With[{plot =
    ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, v1 Cos[t] + v2 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]},
   Graphics[{
     Cases[plot, _Line, Infinity],
     Green, Line[{{0, 0}, v1}], Line[{{0, 0}, v2}],
     Locator[Dynamic[v1]], Locator[Dynamic[v2]]},
    PlotRange -> 3
    ]]]
```

It happens with `Plot`, too.

---

However, the locators work independently if I define the function,

```
SetAttributes[myParamPlot, HoldAll];
myParamPlot[param_, dom_] := Graphics[Line[Table[param, dom]]]
```

and replace `ParametricPlot[..]` with `myParamPlot[param, {t, 0, 1, 1/100}]` in the OP's example or with two calls to `myParamPlot`, one for the circle and one for the transformed circle, in the modified doc. ctr. example.

---

The OP's approach seems reasonable to me, if `Locator` is preferred to `LocatorPane`.  If `LocatorPane` is acceptable, then the `Manipulate`/`DynamicModule` approaches of other answers do not have the unexpected pitfall that the OP encountered.

Comment: Useful answer. I can see that years of study gradually lead to enlightenment about `dynamic`.... I thought there was something about the `p` that caused the flickering but I just removed it instead of trying to work out what was going wrong.